# How do I store strings (or any type) into an array of type T?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I'm trying to store a string (or any type) inside an array of type T, but I get two errors:

> a reference of type "std::string &" (not const-qualified) cannot be
>   initialized with a value of type "const char [3]"
>
> 'bool container::insertBack(T &)': cannot convert
>   argument 1 from 'const char [3]' to 'T &'

I've tried changing the type to int instead of string: I received similar error messages.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
class container
{
public:
    container();
    // Postcondition: data member n is initialized to -1 and all elements in the empty arr array are initialized to zero
    bool isFull();
    // Postcondition: returns true if the container object (i.e., the arr array) is full; returns false otherwise
    bool insertBack(T& val);
    //  Precondition: the container object is not full
    // Postcondition: if arr array is not full, n is incremented by 1; returns true with val is inserted at the end of the arr array 
    //                 Otherwise, returns false; the value is not inserted and program execution continues.
private:
    static const int CAPACITY = 10;     // physical size of the arr array or the storage capacity of a container object
    T arr[CAPACITY];            // arr array can store up to CAPACITY  (10 in our case) of any type 
    int n;                      // n is used as the subscript for the arr array. n is initialized to -1 for an empty array
                                // Each time a new value is inserted into the arr array, n must first be incremented 
                                // by 1. Since n has been initialized to -1, the first inserted value is stored in arr[0],
                                // and the 2nd inserted value will be in arr[1], etc.  and the nth inserted value will be 
                                // stored in arr[n – 1]. Obviously, n + 1 represents the actual number of elements
                                // stored in the array after n rounds of insertion.         
};

template<typename T>
container<T>::container()
{
    n = -1;
    T arr[CAPACITY] = { 0 };
}

template<typename T>
bool container<T>::isFull()
{
    return n == CAPACITY - 1;
}

template<typename T>
bool container<T>::insertBack(T& val)
{
    if (!isFull())
    {
        n++;
        arr[n - 1] = val;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    container<std::string> s1;
    s1.insertBack("aa");
}
```

Comment: Your `bool insertBack(T& val);` requires a reference to a `T` (which is `std::string`) but you provided a string literal, not a `std::string`. You could change it to `bool insertBack(T const& val)` to permit anything convertible to a `std::string`.

Comment: (Note that you're not out of the woods yet, but at least this will get your code to compile so you can start debugging it.)

Comment: @RaymondChen a bit confused about >you provided a string literal, not a std::string; is there a difference between the two: i always believed they were the same

Comment: They are very much different. Even if they were the same, your code still wouldn't compile because `T&` requires an lvalue reference, but you passed a value, not a variable name.

Comment: @S.Coughing A string literal is of type `const char[N]` which in most cases decays to `const char*`. `std::string` has nothing in common with string literals except that it provides a constructor `std::string(const char*)` which makes it implicitely convertible from a string literal.

Comment: Notice that this constructor will copy the string literal / c-string into its own memory

Answer (score 1):

`g++` gives a slightly different output for the same error:

> `cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&' to an rvalue of type 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'`

`clang++`:

> `non-const lvalue reference to type 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'const char [3]'`

The solution is to take the argument as a `const&`.

What you'll find next is that
`T arr[CAPACITY] = { 0 };`
gives a runtime exception like:
`basic_string::_M_construct null not valid`.

You are not zero initializing `arr` like that. In fact, you are creating a new `arr` and trying to construct it with `nullptr`, which will not work for `std::string[]`.

You might as well use an unsigned integer as `size_t` for counting elements as the standard containers do to make future interactions with standard functions/algorithms easier.

With that fixed::

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T, size_t Capacity = 10>       // made the capacity selectable
class container {
public:
    container() : arr{}, n(0) {}                 // using member initializer list

    bool isFull() const { return n == Capacity; } // correct test with a 0 based counter

    bool insertBack(const T& val) {               // const
        if (isFull()) return false;
        // return true or false, not 1 or 0 
        arr[n++] = val;
        return true;
    }

private:
    T arr[Capacity];
    size_t n;
};

int main() {
    container<std::string> s1;
    s1.insertBack("aa");
}
```